# Cant postgresql db rsync to constant db cdb

Tags: javascript, postgresql, lua, powerdns, cdb

Are the ways or setup commands to set triggers on postgresql db (master db) to rsync DJB Constant database (cdb) as soon as update or changes are made instantly?

Comment: surely the whole point of a constant database is it shouldn't be updated frequently? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right but my setup is that I want users to be able change and update their preference settings and profiles stored on postgresql as the master database. Want also rsync master db to constant db in an atomic way. Use cdb for fast DNS queries ie check and lookup if URL or DNS name requested is our blacklisted, malware list and whitelisted db,  etc. cdb is very ideal for this situation. The question is there a script or set of commands which triggers updates or changes to master db rsync  to cdb instance or immediately.

Comment: You could easily enough write a small db client to update the cdb file on a regular basis (the LISTEN facility would be useful here). There is no pre-packaged script that I know of for this, and you will need to cope on the application side with the delay between writing your update and seeing it when querying cdb. Obviously re-reading your whole data-set from PostgreSQL with every update can get expensive quite quickly. My (limited) understanding of cdb is that you can't actually perform an update, just rewrite it.

Comment: Many thanks for your information and assistance. Last thing do u links or info I may read  on how to write a small db client to update the cdb file and update it on a regular basis (listening).  Thanks